# Hola a todos quisiera que me ayudaran con es pequeño problema que tengo y es que trato de sumar dos numeros pero el resultado me da NaN

Tags: javascript

[image: Codigo del problema]

me da como resultado NaN y no entiendo el por que ayudenme

Comment: Agrega el código en lugar de la imagen.

Comment: Es importante que sigas la recomendación que te hacen en los comentarios. Ni es legible ni es viable compartir código como imagen para que quienes intentan responder tengan que transcribirlo desde una imagen. Equivale a que te den respuesta como una imagen y ponerte a transcribir

Comment: a okey muchas lo hice por que apenas me entero de este sitio web y lo hice trascribiendo el codigo pero me decia un error que no entendia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrego correciones al código numeradas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" name="numero" id="numero">
<input type="number" name="numero2" id="numero2">
<input type="button" name="boton" id="btn" value="Sumar"><br>
<label>Resultado</label><br>
<textarea name="resultado" id="resultado" cols="30" rows="5" style="background: $tCOCOCO; color:iH000"></textarea>
<script>


function calcula(){
    
    // 1. el valor del textbox está en la propiedad value
    num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').value);
    num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero2').value);
    // 2. se removió la asignación del evento 'click'
    resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
    // 3. Se llama la función Sumar y se le pasan los argumentos
    // para que funcione
    Sumar(resultado, num1, num2);
}

//4. A la función sumar se le pasa como argumento
// el textarea y num1 y num2
function Sumar(resultado, num1, num2){
  let result = num1 + num2;
  resultado.innerHTML = 'Tu suma es ' + result;
}

//5. en el evento load de la página se asigna el 
// evento click al botón btn
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{

  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', calcula);

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```